# What was the first instance of a relationship between werewolves and vampires?

Tags: history-of, vampire, werewolf

What was the first known instance of a story that provides a relationship between werewolves and vampires? What was that relationship?

In some movies (*Underwold*, *Van Helsing* and *Twilight*), werewolves are portrayed as the vampires' slaves: as the latter represented the aristocratic class, who were on the top food chain thanks to their human-like appearance and self-control. Totally the opposite for the werewolves, who were simply seen like savage beasts, who cannot control themselves (*Twilight*, *Underworld*).

Comment: Both "monsters" are older than the written word and are encountered in various shapes and forms across multiple cultures all over the world. Apparently the idea that those creatures exist is even older than the concept of slaves, classes, aristocrats and so on. Asking about the original relationship, well, if there was one, it's lost forever and it would be different for every single tribe that believed in such things in 20k BC (or something). Could you maybe explain what you mean by "original"?

Comment: I never heard of any connections between werewolves and vampires in old stories. They're unrelated monsters.

Comment: I think we need to clarify what you mean by "original relationship."  Certainly the origins of each are independent, as Zabeus says.  Are you asking for the first known instance of a story that provides a relationship between them, and if so what that relationship was?  Are you asking for the first known instance of a relationship similar to the one you describe?

Comment: I would also say, even in today's literature, that there's no *expectation* of a relationship between vampires and werewolves.  Each author is free to define such a relationship as they see fit.

Comment: @Steve-O Yes that's exactly what i want, in other words why the werewolf is the slave and the vampire the master. Is that how it started ? Or it changed through the time. Thanks for clarifying my question..

Comment: @MOTZI It would be wise to edit the question body to clarify what you're really looking for, so people don't have to read down the comment chain (after a while they get collapsed/hidden.)

Comment: Yes, TheLethalCarrot just did 

Comment: I'm still not sure what's being asked. The title implies *romantic* relationship, but the body seems unclear. These comments don't help either.

Comment: I believe that in old folk tales werewolves and vampires were treated often as the same creature - a human that can turn into a wolf and drinks blood.